# Conversion from UTF8 to Unicode in NSString iOS

Tags: ios

I don't see any direct NSString function converting UTF8 to Unicode string? Do I need to use third party codes to do the conversion?

any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is it that you want? `NSString` can produce char buffers in any encoding you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty easy. First you get the string' length, [str length], then you get a pointer to the unichar bytes (unichar is UTF-16 more or less):

```
unichar unibuffer[length];
[str getCharacters:unibuffer range:NSRangeMake(0, length]];
```

Comment: Oops - I looked at acceptance ratio per comment above. My mistake here - I'm tired - I usually never post for someone with less than 50%. @Kevin Ballard sorry didn't see your comment